# validation column of two data frame

Tags: r

I have two data frame, df8, df9, now i am checking if "name" column in df8 is blank or space or NA then mutate new column "blank_name" as 1, else 0 but i don't want to change the original column "Name" for city in (CY) .I am trying the below way but doesn't work for me.

also I want to check if id of df8 present in df9 then i want to check if name is consistent with name in df9

I am trying like below, the common column is df9[id] and df8[code]

```
df9 <- data.frame(id=c(3109,2357,4339,8927,9143,4285,2683,8217,3702,7857,3255,4262,8501,7111,2681,6970),
                  name=c("try,xab","xab,Lan","mhy,mun","vgtu,mmc","dgsy,aaf","kull,nnhu","hula,njam","mund,jiha","htfy,ntha","","sgyu,hytb","vdti,kula","mftyu,huta","","cday,bhsue","ajtu,nudj"))
                  
df8 <- data.frame(code=c(3109,2357,4339,8927,9143,4285,2683,8217,3702,7857,3255,4262,8501,7111,2681,6970),
                  city = c("CY","NY","DA","CY","MN","GA","MN","CY","NY","DA","CY","CY","GA","CY","LA","DA"),
                  name=c("try,xab","xab,Lan","mhy,mun","vgtu,mmc","   ","kull,nnhu","hula,njam","mund,jiha","htfy,ntha",NA,"sgyu,hytb","vdti,kula","mftyu,huta","","cday,bhsue","ajtu,nudj"))



df8 <- df8 %>%
    mutate(
      name=if_else(city=="CY", name, str_trim(name)),
      blank = case_when(
        is.na(name)~1,
        str_length(name)==0~1,
        TRUE~0
      )
    )
  
  df9 %>%
    rename(name.9=name) %>%
    right_join(df8_update, by=c("id"="code") %>%
    mutate(if_name_ok= case_when(
      is.na(name) & is.na(name.9)~ 0,
      is.na(name) & blank==1 ~0,
      name == name.9 ~0,
      name != name.9~1,
      TRUE ~ NA_real_
    ))
```

the output should be two mutated column with values 0 and 1 for True and False

Comment: The cod you show for creating `blank_nodename` looks fine... is it giving you trouble? What is the problem?

Comment: just updated function but  "name" works fine, but i have issue in if_name_ok

Comment: Are you looking for `df9 %>%  rename(name.9=name) %>% right_join(df8, by=c("id"="code")) %>%mutate(if_name_ok= case_when(is.na(name) & is.na(name.9)~ 0,is.na(name) & blank==1 ~0,name == name.9 ~0,name != name.9~1,TRUE ~ NA_real_)) ` ?

Comment: yes it works , but also for NA values it should show 1 for if_name_ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following :

```
library(dplyr)

df9 %>%  
  rename(name.9=name) %>% 
  right_join(df8, by=c("id"="code")) %>%
  mutate(if_name_ok= case_when((is.na(name) & is.na(name.9)) | 
                               (is.na(name) & blank==1) | 
                               (name == name.9) ~ 0,
                               name != name.9~1,
                               TRUE ~ 1))
```

Comment: but if i dont want any column from df8, i want if_name_ok blank column only

Comment: After this you can `select` the columns that you want to keep. `%>% select(if_name_ok, blank)`.